# Setting up OpenID Provider with SubDomains Identifiers using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am currently trying to implement an OpenID Provider on my own domain name.
Thus, I would like the OpenID Identifier of a user to be **user.example.com** instead of the default **example.com/user.aspx/user**..

Is it possible for DotNetOpenAuthto do that? If so, roughly what changes do i need to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible.

1. Configure your DNS and web site(s) and IIS to actually respond to **user.example.com**.
2. Place a default.aspx file such that it responds to requests for that domain, and make that URL an OpenID Claimed Identifier by placing the tags in it that you find in the **user.aspx** sample.  Be sure in those tags that point to your *OP Endpoint* that it uses the absolute URL (which may be **http://www.example.com/provider.ashx**)
3. Modify your **provider.ashx** (or **server.aspx**, or MVC action, whatever you're using for your OP Endpoint) to be willing to send assertions for **user.example.com**

And you're done.  I haven't gone into great detail on these steps because it's the same steps you take when you customize the URL of your claimed identifiers in any way -- special host name or not.  The only really special step is #1: Configuring IIS.  To accept any random host name requires special DNS configuration, but since it's just your own user name you can just hard-code your username into DNS.